# How to make device appear in file manager in list of devices pane when mounting manually

Tags: mount

How to manually mount a device so that it appears in file manager as disk/drive?

ADDED:

Sometimes device is not mounted automatically (and does not appear in `Disks`) or needed to be mounted with specific options. Doing like

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/data
```

does not make device appear in file manager in the left pane with other devices and I could not find option for `mount` command to make new mount appear as device in file manager (Nemo specfically).

Comment: Please clarify if you need the drive automatically mounted at login.

Comment: Also, add the file system type of the drive to be mounted.

Comment: @Vlastimil, please see my comment to Debian_yadav answer to see why I need to mount manually. Also mounting manually is useful in other cases too, like wanting specific mounting options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount to `/media/user_name/disk_name`, replacing `user_name` with your user name, and `disk_name` to what you like, not to `/mnt`.

Can use `x-mount.mkdir` option to automatically create `disk_name` folder. 
I do not know yet how to make folder automatically deleted on unmount.

P.S. Tested on Linux Mint 18.3 with Nemo file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to mount it manually then use GUI. Go to `disks` then select the mount option to mount the disk. There you will find option to automatically mount the disk during startup.

Comment: I came to the issue when device is not mounted automatically for some reason and in some cases like today it is not shown in Disks (don't know why but second USB stick on my Thinkpad did not automount - both work fine when inserted separately in any USB ports). From  GUI only Gparted saw it but it had only format, not mount option.

Comment: @ Debian_yadav, I've written above, rephrased: "device is not seen in Disks" (gnome-disk-utility 3.18.3.1 in distro I use mostly).

Answer (score 0):

When using disks, when you check mark show in user interface an addtional mount option is added `x-gvfs-show` and it helps you to show.

this is from `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ba6274de-e241-43ef-9dd0-5147c29e883a /mnt/500GB_Seagate_Drive auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=480%20GB%20Seagate%20Internal%20Drive 0 0
```

[image]